# An approximation for the Lambert W-function

Tags: proof-writing, approximation, lambert-w

**Proposition**

Let $f(x) = k^{x}x$, where the values of both $f(x)$ and $k$ are known.

Let $x_{0} = f(x)$, and:

$$x_{n + 1} = \frac{1}{2}\log_{k}{\left(\frac{k^{x_{n}}x_{0}}{x_{n}}\right)}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{n}} = x$$

I was wondering how one could prove this. I derived it in rather an odd manner.

Thank you.

Comment: "I derived it in rather an odd manner" Show the "rather odd manner".

Comment: @Did I will have to add that a bit later as I am on my phone and it is incredibly tedious to write the LaTeX.

Comment: Taylor, could you please add in the derivation now?

Answer (score 0):

I note the following:

$$x_{n+1}=\frac12\log_k\left(\frac{k^{x_n}x_0}{x_n}\right)=\frac12(x_n+\log_k\left(\frac{x_0}{x_n}\right))$$

$$x_0=x_0$$
$$x_1=\frac12x_0$$
$$x_2=\frac12(\frac12x_0+\log_k(2))$$

And so I find it slightly difficult, finding a proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$, but I will most certainly enjoy seeing it.